# How does the Ubuntu bug list relate to individual packages' bug lists?

Tags: bug-reporting

For example, in [issue 453](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue453) of the Ubuntu newsletter, the following can be read:

> #### Bug Stats
>
> - Open (118560) -218 over last week
> - Critical (315) +8 over last week
> - Unconfirmed (58076) -308 over last week

As far as I understand these are bugs covering all the packages available in the Ubuntu repositories.

If so, how do these bugs relate to the individual packages' bug lists?

Take for example QEMU. Are the same bugs that are reported on [the QEMU bug list](https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu) duplicated onto [the Ubuntu bug list](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/)?

How does it work?

Comment: The short answer to your question about whether bug lists are duped in Ubuntu and upstream projects is "No".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bugs can be associated with both projects and distributions:

[image]

The Ubuntu bug list contains only those which list Ubuntu as an affected distribution:

[image]

Take, for example, [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/1192081). It is associated with both Ubuntu, and the [unity-lens-applications](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-lens-applications) project. It will show up in both bug lists. [This QEMU bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1174654) will be in both lists.

Comment: Do all packages in the Ubuntu repositories have a corresponding buglist on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ ? If not, how are the bugs tracked for the packages that are not bugtracked on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ ?

Comment: @Markus Yes. You can get to it by going to `https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/<source-package>`. The source package is listed at the top of `http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/<package>`.